# React-native-onesignal : duplicate error with Pods

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native, onesignal

I'm losing my mind on a problem since 1 entire week...
I have a ReactNative project, that runs very well on Android Simulator, but not on Xcode.

1. ***My code***

Actually, I have in my package.json :

> Package.json

```
...
"react": "15.4.2",
"react-native": "^0.40.0",
...
"react-native-onesignal": "^3.0.3",
...
```

I can run `npm install` or `npm update` without any error.

Furthermore, I have in my Podfile, for my iOS project, in the iOS folder:

> Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'OneSignal'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

When I run `pod install`, it's working well and create the .xcworkspace file. When I open it, I can see the first error:

[image: Error in finding file]

So I have googled it, and found the react-native-onesignal repo on GitHub, with a recommendation from the developer about my problem: he says to correctly follow [iOS installation steps](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal#ios-installation).
I have done it, by adding in `Header Search Path` this : `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/ios` in `recursive` :
[image: Add header properly]

Now, OneSignal.h is found, but I get a new error telling me that the library is duplicated:
[image: Error duplicate]

For information, here is my library, my files, and my build phases:

> Library in General

[image: Library]

> Files in Xcode

[image: Files]

> Build Phases

[image: Build phases]

---

2. ***What I have tried***

I have tried to:

- delete the main.m, since it seems to be duplicated,

  - delete one copy of the library, in both library in General or Library in Build phases,
  - delete manually one copy in the files system in Xcode,
  - remove `$(inherited)` flag in `Other Files Flag` in my target Build Settings: the build succeeded, but my app is not working anymore
    ... I tried to remove other flags, but no results.

No solutions and I'm getting mad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved my problem.
In fact, my package.json was installing react-native-onesignal in version ^3.0.2, so 3.0.3 currently. Hence, since 3.0.3 has removed CocoaPods from process, it was not running... I put in package.json **'3.0.2'**.
I will remove Cocoapods and use 3.0.3 later.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.40, react-native doesn't play along well with cocoapods. I had a similar fight for days, it got solved only when dropping cocoapods completely.
But before giving up, try also deleting derived data folder which can be found at `Xcode > File > Project Settings`.